# Glosario de términos en español

Tags: discusión, traducciones

En los metas de [SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) y [SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) existe una terminología establecida para determinados casos y usos que puede consultarse y sienta las bases para un lenguaje común entre los participantes.

Creo que nosotros también deberíamos definir una ya que todos los términos no se traducen igual y pueden generar cierta confusión a la hora de leerlos.

Aquí van algunas propuestas:

*Original Poster* (OP) =>  *Autor Orignal* (AO)

*Accept Rate* => *Grado de Aceptación* (GA)

*Accepted Answer* => *Respuesta Aceptada* (RA)

*Comunity Manager* (CM) => *Moderador de la Comunidad* (MC)

*Comunity Wiki* (CW) => *Wiki de la Comunidad* (WC)

*Close Vote* (CV) => *Voto de Cierre* (VC)

*Fastest Gun in the West* => *Vaquero*

*Locked* => *Sellado*

*Off-topic* (OT) => *No relacionado* (NR)

*Sock Pupet* (SP) => *Cuenta fantasma* (CF)

Nota: Las abreviaturas están encerradas entre paréntesis.

**Referencias:**

[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

[What is an OP when referring to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange)

[What is the term for the person offering the bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295823/what-is-the-term-for-the-person-offering-the-bounty)

Comment: El término `establecido(a)` da la impresión de que se trata de algo impuesto autoritariamente. Me parece que va a causar rechazo.

Comment: Al buscar "Autor Original" en meta de SOes el único resultado es esta pregunta. Me parece que va a ocurrir lo mismo con los demás términos. Creo que este tema salió demasiado pronto.

Comment: Lo siento, me niego a escribir "esta respuesta debería ser WC" :-)

Comment: ami personalmente no me parece tan mala pregunta, si bien es cierto que yo no uso acronimos/abreviaturas de forma habitual, la iniciativa de crearlas me parece buena idea y mas aun si esta sera consultada por usuarios nuevo que no tenga conocimientos de SO. Puedes usarlos o no pero de usarlos que menos que tener un lugar donde consultarlos y ese lugar podria este Saludos

Comment: @Konamiman: Afortunadamente "WC" aún no se usa en [meta] (sin contar esta discusión) :)

Answer (score 3):

Particularmente no me gusta esta idea.

El motivo por el que existen esos temas en el sitio en inglés es que en ese idioma es muy común escribir usando todo tipo de acrónimos.

En el sitio en español no me parece buena idea ya que no es la forma normal de escritura, sobre todo si se trata de traducir los ya existentes.

Mi recomendación es **no utilizar acrónimos o abreviaturas sino escribir la palabra completa**. Esto permite que todos puedan entender el mensaje sin necesidad de estar consultando una lista (esta pregunta) que probablemente no sea obvia para los nuevos usuarios.

Claro está que esto **no aplica a términos y/o abreviaturas comúnmente utilizados** en el idioma español en lugar de términos específicos a *Stack Overflow* u otros sitios del mismo tipo.

Comment: Una de las razones por la que existen esas abreviaturas es porque son muy usadas en el Meta donde los usuarios estan familiarizados con la terminología y tambien en los comentarios que están limitados a 600 caracteres por lo que a veces se hace necesario el uso de abreviaturas. Si yo tuviera que escribir Autor Original estaría usando 14 caracteres en lugar de 2. Esas situaciones se darán tarde o temprano y lo que ocurrirá es que cada cual usará sus propios términos en lugar de un lenguaje común.

Comment: @devconcept `[..] y lo que ocurrirá es que cada cual usará sus propios términos en lugar de un lenguaje común.` y así es como eventualmente nacerá un lenguaje común, no diseñado sino naturalmente favoreciendo las palabras con mayor uso.

Comment: Así que esperamos ... y eventualmente todos editamos la pregunta... ;) Ahora entiendo que no se quiera poner toda la lista pero al menos hay términos que son muy usados y realmente me he visto en la obligación de inventar algunas alternativas para poder representar el "sujeto en cuestión", por eso se me ocurrió la idea de escribir la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La intención es bastante buena, pero considero que el planteamiento debería ser muy diferente.

En primer lugar, debe plantearse con un recurso de ayuda no como una ley o doctrina.  Por otro lado, al ser una "WC" (no se refiere a "Water Closet" / Sanitario / baño sino a *wiki de comunidad*) me parece que sería complicadísimo tener un buena coordinación por la diversidad de opiniones que seguramente habrá.

Una alternativa es realizar una adaptación o al menos con una estructura similar a la primer referencia de la pregunta. Me refiero a [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms). De esta me parece sobresaliente el siguiente planteamiento:

> When considering whether a term ought to be included, please use this
>   test:
>
> New user comes in and posts on day 1. What terminology or jargon are
>   they likely to run into (comments, support, system messages, etc.)
>   that cannot be understood from the context without prior experience
>   with the site (that is, clear only if known). For example: "This is a
>   dupe. Flag a diamond mod to close or migrate to SU." Huh? Can these
>   instruction be made clear from the glossary? Is it clear for those for
>   whom English is a second language?

Cuya adaptación podría ser

Cuando se considere si un término debe ser incluído, reflexionar sobre lo siguiente:

Un nuevo usuario llega y publica en el día 1. ¿Cuál es la terminología o jerga que enfrentará (comentarios, soporte, mensajes del sistema, etc) que no puede ser entendida en el contexto sin contar con experiencia previa con el sitio? Por ejemplo, "Es un dup. Repórtalo a un diamante para cerrarlo" ¿Eh? ¿Una instrucción como esta podría ser clarificada en el glosario? ¿Es esta clara para quien habla cualquier variante del castellano (mexicano, colombiano, argentino,...) ?