# ¿Conviene crear alternativa a OP para SOes?

Tags: discusión, glosario

Me explico, en SOes estamos acostumbrados a decir que, el *Original Poster* (OP), para referirnos a la persona que creó la pregunta de la cual se tiene contexto. Hace unos minutos en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39158399#39158399) alguien me explicó el significado de esto, a lo cual, nació la siguiente duda:

**¿Vale la pena crear nuestra versión de  *OP* para SOes?** 
Para cualquiera de las dos respuestas (sí/no) yo,  el *Posteador original/Original poster(OP)* me gustaría saber el porqué de su pensar.

**EDIT**

A lo que yo me refiero con la palabra ***Conviene***, es, a que si valdría la pena crear nuestra propia versión de las siglas OP, ya que es un término en inglés, y bueno, esto es SOes, así que no suena tan loco tener una manera específica para llamar a nuestros OP.

Comment: Por favor define a que te refieres con "conviene" ya que sin tener esto claro aún para meta parece una pregunta demasiado amplia.

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta, espero ser más claro con esto @Rubén

Comment: Mi opinión personal es que iría con el principio KISS. "OP" es algo que ya entendemos, ¿qué valor concreto se gana con tener una traducción de eso? Me recuerda a una discusión de hace poco entre array y arreglo. Hay términos que en inglés ya entendemos y ya nos apoyan. Tratar de españolizar (¿?) todo no da tanto valor como lo esperado.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo: Cuando se hace un "edit", en particular cuando aún no hay respuestas ni votos, es mejor integrar la nueva información de forma orgánica más que anexar al final la explicación de lo que se quiso decir. Piensa en facilitar las cosas a los que leerán por primera vez la pregunta y para los que han siguen la pregunta desde la publicación original, considera que está el historial de revisiones.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ oh, entiendo, tiene mucho sentido cuando lo planteas de esa manera.

Comment: Por cierto, esto ya se abordó en [Glosario de términos en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341/65)

Comment: @Rubén lo siento por ello, la costumbre jajaja, le daré una leída a ese enlace, gracias por responder :)

Comment: Se abordo la idea y al parecer no tuvo mucho éxito

Comment: Pues creo que __si debería__ haber un manual o glosario de términos, para que cuando alguien pregunte _"WTF es OP"_ otro le diga _"LOL RTFM"_... sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

No conviene crear una nueva versión localizada pero en mi opinión tampoco conviene quedarnos con *OP*

Si bien muchas personas saben de que se trata el término, en mi opinión exagerar con el uso de las siglas como es común en inglés no ayuda a que el significado sea claro.

Por mi parte cuando me tengo que referir al **Original Poster** simplemente me refiero a el o ella como el *autor de la pregunta* o mejor aún uso su **@Nombre**

Esto no quiere decir que este mal usar *OP*, pienso que por ejemplo las publicaciones o comentarios que ya están con *OP* no deban ser editados siemplemente para cambiar el término desatando una guerra de ediciones, simplemente me parece que es cuestión de preferencias.

Comment: *simplemente me parece que es cuestión de preferencias* esto es clave. Como una comunidad de gente que habla español, pero cada uno con sus modismos, me parece que es súper importante respetar las preferencias individuales. En lo personal, prefiero hablar de OP. Entiendo que haya quienes prefieran decir "el autor". Creo que es clave respetar lo que cada uno prefiera, para tener una comunidad que incluya a cada uno hablando como se sienta más cómodo.

Answer (score 2):

Primero se habla o escribe. Después se crean abreviaturas de las cosas que se usan con mucha frecuencia. No empieces creando una abreviatura.

Yo ya lo hago, con frecuencia uso la exprexión "el autor original de la pregunta". Si dices eso todo castellanoparlante sabrá a que te refieres.

¿Conviene? Claro, que te entiendan es conveniente. Tener que mirar una página aparte de abreviaturas o preguntas frecuentes no es conveniente.